# is there any way to convert string to int for any array?

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] WS1_AF = File.ReadAllLines("WS1_AF.txt");
}
```

Not sure how to convert to integer from string

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines("WS1_AF.txt");
```

and then convert it array of int

```
int[] WS1_AF = Array.ConvertAll(readText , int.Parse);
```